# Configuring Emmet to Work on EJS files (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I've begun writing a NodeJS web app with `.ejs` files for templating my views. I'm trying to get Emmet to work on `.ejs` extensions as well as `.html` extensions in Sublime Text 3. Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you already installed `emmet` and configured the key binding for the `emmet-sublime` https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet. In other to make the `emmet` work with `.ejs` you simply install the `ejs` package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EJS.

---

then just close all the `.ejs` files, reopen them. now you can `#root` and hit `tab` in your `.ejs` files.